# Search a part of a description

Tags: excel, search, vba

Is there a way that i can search a part of a description in a cell?
because when i search for a part like UTP he give's me an error

Got anny idea?

Here is my code

```
'search for a cbxItem_Nr or a cbx_Description
Sub Find_test_click()
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    FindString = InputBox("Voer de product code in")
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Magazijn").Range("A:B") 'searches all of column A and B
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True 'value found
            Else
                MsgBox "Opgegeven product Niet gevonden" '(MsgBox) Saying Did not find the product
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

In the code there are some dutch words

Comment: Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: You're want to use `InStr`, if you want to find a string within another string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the question, but maybe try to use "xlPart" instead of "xlWhole" as lookAt-parameter.

Comment: @DarkPower15 If this answer solved your question then please [mark this answer as the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Like this other users on this site know that this question has been solved and does not require their attention anymore. Furthermore, it allows users to find this answer if they have a similar problem. Finally, the user posting this answer will get rewarded with points. This is the generally accepted way for showing your appreciation for the help you received. You may also opt to up-vote this answer for an even greater "thank you".